# Excel Multiple Series Chart with Time on x-axis

Tags: excel, time, scatter-plot, x-axis

I have two series of daily data, displayed on a **Scatter Plot** with date on the x-axis. One series is orange, the other is blue. Here is the chart:
[Scatter Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVhHg.png)

The x-axis labels appear on the major tick marks every 100 days. I want the labels to appear on the first day of every third month.

Is there a way to get a regular spacing of x-axis labels based on the number of months in a **Scatter Plot**?

When I try to do this in a **Line Chart** I get this:
[Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hS4qY.png)

Note that the orange series in the **Line Chart** has moved all the way to the left of the chart where it does not belong.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around.

I use a **Line Plot** and I enter 0's for the dates where no information exists. The plot can be seen here: [Line Graph with Extra Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coZBY.png)

This is for a deliverable so I don't want to show all those zeros. I went ahead and made the points I don't want invisible. This can be done manually (right-click a datapoint and select "Format Data Point" then select "No Line") but there are ~500 datapoints in this graph and I have about 20 graphs so I automated it with the following lines of code:

```
For i = 1 To A1
    oChart.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Points(i).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Next
```

I was already using the variable A1 as the row where I wanted the orange curve to begin. oChart is the shape object that holds the graph.

The end result is here: [Corrected Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH75K.png)

It still seems like there should be a way to do this with a **Scatter Plot** and I'd appreciate it if anyone could show me how to do that.